# Scikit use list in train set for MLP

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, neural-network, training-data

I want to train a neural network (Multi-Perceptron) with the following data:

```
1              2              3             Other Field   Label
[1, 2, 3, 4]   [5, 6, 7, 8]   [9, 10, 11]   1234          5678
etc...
```

Here `1`, `2` and `3` are columns that contain a list. The other two columns just have numeric values.

Only I keep getting this:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Is this even possible?

Edit:
My code to train the neural network is as follows:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
mlp = MLPClassifier(alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10), random_state=1)
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Here's a screenshot of my train data:

[image]

And my label is just one column with numbers.

Comment: dont see any scikit specific code thats malfunctioning. Maybe add your code?

Comment: Done @PatrickArtner

Comment: Nice, data could have been text but you provided some "example data" - now wait and watch the SO magic happen :) +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lists always have the same length, it's just an issue of splitting each list-column into four individual columns, like described e.g. [here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_expand_cells_containing_lists.html):

```
# create a dataset
raw_data = {'score': [1,2,3], 
        'tags': [['apple','pear','guava'],['truck','car','plane'],['cat','dog','mouse']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['score', 'tags'])
# expand df.tags into its own dataframe
tags = df['tags'].apply(pd.Series)
# rename each variable
tags = tags.rename(columns = lambda x : 'tag_' + str(x))
# join the tags dataframe back to the original dataframe
df = pd.concat([df[:], tags[:]], axis=1)
df.drop('tags', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

If not, the best answer might be problem-specific. One approach could be to extend each list to the length of the longest list by padding with filler values and then doing the same.